# Xcode objective C++ -- avoid making .hh files?

Tags: xcode, objective-c++

To get header files with both Objective C and C++ objects to work, I have to rename them from .h to .hh.  But my colleague uses .h with no problems.  Neither of us understands why.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: You can leave of the extension entirely. The `.h` isn't important. You can `#import` or `#include` any file you want, even `/dev/random` if you'd like. What about using `#ifdef`s to check the language?

Comment: I'm talking about the name of the file.

Comment: I can use an ifdef to import a file -- tho that is ugly as hell.  But I can't use an ifdef to pick a filename.  My concern is not compatibility with my colleague.  It is -- why do I need to do the renaming.

Comment: Yeah, I personally use `.doubleBaconCheeseburger` for my headers.

Answer (score 5):

I guess your colleague's project settings have the *Compile Sources As* set to Objective-C++ and you don't.