# When use hpp and when use h + cpp?

Tags: c++, header-files

For my understanding, hpp is the combination of h and cpp. When I looking into source code, I found sometimes hpp is preferred and sometimes h + cpp is preferred. But I don't know the reason. Could you help me to explain it?

Comment: "*For my understanding, hpp is the combination of h and cpp*" - your understanding is wrong. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152555/h-or-hpp-for-your-class-definitions).

Comment: `For my understanding, hpp is the combination of h and cpp.` No. `.hpp` is often used for header files in c++ projects to not confuse them with c header files.

Answer (score 0):

> and sometimes h + cpp is preferred. But I don't know the reason. Could you help me to explain it?

That may depend on how the build system works.

There are cases that you want to expose a c-style API (usually indicated with the `.h` extension) but have an implementation written in c++ (`.cpp`).
The build system should be able wich compile mode (plain c or c++) should be used to handle translation units.

---

In general: Pairing [`.hpp` `.hxx`, `.hh`, `.h++`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354321/c-reason-why-using-hh-as-extension-for-c-header-files) with a `.cpp` translation unit is the right way to make the build system rules happy.